# jQuery imgAreaSelect - issue with image and area selection passed from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I've just started working the jquery umgareaselect and I think its just what I need, however I have an issue with the image I've uploaded. The upload script is working fine and the image is successfully saved to a folder called 'upload' on the server. I use a couple of asp variables to store the location of the file just uploaded. 
If I reference the url directly of the image directly in the 'src' tag the initially selected area works fine, however if I use the variables from ASP (like the code below) then the image is loaded and displayed correctly but the initially selected area cannot be moved or selected. I hope the code below helps:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>  
<body>
<%image_name = request.form("image_name")%>
<%mainurl = request.form("mainurl")%>

  <form action="aspimage_DEMO3.asp" method="post" target="_blank" id="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js">    
 </script>    

 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
$('#ladybug_ant').imgAreaSelect({ x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 40, y2: 40 });
 });

 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#ladybug_ant').imgAreaSelect({
    onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
        $('input[name="x1"]').val(selection.x1);
        $('input[name="y1"]').val(selection.y1);
        $('input[name="x2"]').val(selection.x2);
        $('input[name="y2"]').val(selection.y2);     

      }
   });
 });

   </script>

   </head>
   <body>

  <%   
 %>
 <img src=<%response.write(mainurl)%><%response.write(image_name)%> id="ladybug_ant"      style="height:200px;width:300px;"><br>


  </body>
 </html>
```

So the 'mainurl' variable is just the 'http://www.website.co.uk' and the 'image-name' variable is the '/uploads/imagename.jpg'.
The img src tag works fine in the respect of displaying the image but the initially selected area cant be moved anywhere and when I press submit the co ordinates for cropping and not displayed. I know this is something straightforward to achieve I just cant seem to nail it, A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks
Kev

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, If I understood your question correctly..IF you are trying to make the selection area according to the input coordinate value..here you go

```
 var edit_box = $('#ID').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
                         //give the coordinates here
                        edit_box.setSelection(x1,y1,x2,y2, true);
                        edit_box.setOptions({ show: true });
                        edit_box.update();
```

This will set the selection box on the image where you want..Hope it helps